# ES6 backtick support in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, ecmascript-6

In my Sublime Text 3 (build 3065), ES6 string interpolation backticks seem to confuse the syntax highlighting in html files. For example

```
console.log(`"`)
```

would lead the syntax highlighting to assume we have an unmatched quote here, rather than figuring this is a single quotation mark quoted by backticks - which renders the remainder of the source file useless in terms of code highlighting.

Has this been solved in an updated build or add-on?

Meanwhile I can workaround it by closing the imaginary quotation in a comment.

```
console.log(`"`) // "
```

Comment: :-) looking at the colors above, looks like the SE syntax highlighter currently has the same problem with backticks

Answer (score 6):

You will need to install a separate package for syntax highlighting in Sublime. There is currently a TextMate/Sublime 2 package for this (which should work for Sublime 3) here: https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage

[From the Installation and Use heading](https://github.com/Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage#installation-and-use):

> If you haven't already, install Package Control, then select
> JavaScript Next from the Package Control: Install Package dropdown
> list in the Command Palette.
>
> To set this as your default JavaScript syntax, open a javascript file,
> then select View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... ->
> JavascriptNext.
>
> You may also need to change the ColorScheme. Pick one from Preferences
> -> Color Scheme -> JavaScriptNext.

EDIT: Original Answerer posted a more widely used highlighter in comment below. It is here:
[github.com/babel/babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime)

Comment: this worked for you (or anyone else) with sublime 3?

Comment: Sublime 3 supports the same tmLanguage syntax definition format as Sublime 2. I think there are currently three choices: Babel-Sublime (which is derived from JSNext) and I'm pretty sure there's also one called ESNext. Babel-Sublime has JSX support, but also fixes several bugs from JSNext. It's the one I would recommend right now.

Comment: @matt For reference: https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime I've never seen this one, but it looks really good. Especially seeing that it is maintained by one of the most popular ES6 projects :) Thanks Semicolon